# How to configure PuTTY so that Home/End/PgUp/PgDn work properly in bash?

Tags: bash, putty

The keys Home, End, PageUp, PageDown all type a `~` in my bash session instead of moving the cursor / view around. Why does this happen and which settings do I need to change?

```
GNU bash, version 4.0.28(1)-release (x86_64--netbsd)
PuTTY v0.60
```

---

The question originally read:

In PuTTY, why does pressing the "Home" key on the shell (bash) type a "~"? Or rather, how do I make it move the cursor to the start of the command I've typed?

(I thought the reason was that ~ is the *home* directory, but the answers say this is not so.)

Comment: I can't post an answer here. But if you're trying to use those buttons _from the numeric keyboard_ then it can be solved very easily: go to _Settings > Terminal > Features_ and enable `Disable application keypad mode`

Answer (score 186, accepted):

Under the *Connection* > *Data* tab, change the *Terminal-type string*  from the default “xterm” to “linux”. It worked for me.

[image: Screenshot of relevant setting]

Comment: Thanks! I had this problem after I tred to make Ctrl Left/Right work using this method (http://superuser.com/a/103097/45410).

Comment: Emphasis: not `Terminal -> Keyboard` "The Function keys and keypad".

Comment: It works but creates other problems like disabling mouse support. so, it is not acceptable solution for me

Comment: This solution also enables umlauts inside putty when connecting to OS X!

Comment: found one major problem with this solution. When copy pasting a long bash script from windows to vi in putty, top section gets truncated. Recommend setting Terminal-type string to "putty" instead.

Comment: ... or, to add to the comment by @tinker: set the terminal type string `putty-256color` or do it inside your shell altogether by exporting `TERM=putty` or `TERM=putty-256color`.

Answer (score 54):

This is happening because you don't have PuTTY's terminal type set correctly, or because your server doesn't have the correct terminfo definitions installed.

On Debian-based systems, the *ncurses-term* package (version 5.7+20081213-1) includes terminfo definition files for *putty*, *putty-256color* and *putty-vt100* terminal types.  If you have this package installed, you can set the "Terminal-type string" to "putty" instead of the default "xterm" in Putty's session configuration (Connection -> Data).

Stephen Irons also mentions "linux" as another terminal type that works; I believe this is correct from prior experience, but haven't tested it recently.

On my systems, this allows Home and End to work correctly, though PageUp/PageDown do not scroll the console window.  (They do work properly in ncurses applications like *aptitude*, and Shift-PgUp/Shift-PgDn scroll the console window.)

Comment: Yes, using `TERM=putty` or `TERM=putty-256color` is wisest, though unfortunately at the moment the latter doesn't seem to work right for colors 8-15 (which are supposed to be the bright versions of 0-7). The other "solutions" are are very likely to flake out sometimes do to their flagrant disregard of the differences between the terminals involved.

Comment: ```yum install ncurses-term``` sorted it for me on CentOS 7 with putty on next login, thank you.

Comment: setting terminal type to `putty` works but breaks xterm-like mouse support (e.g. for Midnight Commander)

Comment: installing 'ncurses-term' worked for me on Debian testing.

Comment: none of these work for me, I am on putty connecting to centos, and can't run yum install ncurses-term because I am not root.

Answer (score 26):

If you want to verify which code is sent by PuTTY to your terminal when you press a key or a combination of keys, you just have to issue a `Ctrl+V` and then press on the desired key.

For example on my box, pressing the *Home* key will generate the following string on my terminal:

```
^[[1~
```

That means that PuTTY sends the escape character **^[** followed by the string **[1~**.

You can create an `~/.inputrc` file in your `$HOME` folder, or alternatively an `/etc/inputrc` file depending on your system. Then fill this file with the PuTTY codes and the matching Bash actions you want to be triggered by Bash.

*Note: Replace every **^[** character by the equivalent **\e** string*

In my example, I'll add a line with my *Home* key code and the *beginning-of-line* action (which by default is bound to `Ctrl+A` in Bash):

```
"\e[1~": beginning-of-line
```

FYI, my inputrc file has the following content:

```
set meta-flag on
set input-meta on
set convert-meta off
set output-meta on
"\e[1~": beginning-of-line     # Home key
"\e[4~": end-of-line           # End key
"\e[5~": beginning-of-history  # PageUp key
"\e[6~": end-of-history        # PageDown key
"\e[3~": delete-char           # Delete key
"\e[2~": quoted-insert         # Insert key
"\eOD": backward-word          # Ctrl + Left Arrow key
"\eOC": forward-word           # Ctrl + Right Arrow key
```

From @Cimbali: More bindable commands (like previous-history: Move `up' through the history list) available [on this reference page](http://web.mit.edu/gnu/doc/html/features_7.html#SEC51).

Comment: YES ! Finally ! Putty's terminal-type string didn't do anything for backward-word and forward-word. This is great !

Comment: This is the only acceptable solution because `TERM=linux` or `TERM=putty` break xterm-like mouse support. Thanks!

Answer (score 14):

Crtl+A takes you to the start of the line

Here's a [list of Bash keyboard shortcuts](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/ubuntu/keyboard-shortcuts-for-bash-command-shell-for-ubuntu-debian-suse-redhat-linux-etc/)

Comment: That's great and all, but Home/End are hard-wired in my brain, and since I only administer the server once in a blue moon the chances of unlearning the hard-wiring are slim.

Answer (score 10):

What it's actually sending is `^[[1~` which is a terminal escape sequence consisting of:

- ^[ - escape
- [ - left square bracket
- 1 - one
- ~ - tilde

You can see that by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> then <kbd>Home</kbd>.

You might be able to fix your problem by changing the PuTTY keyboard setting for Home and End keys to rxvt (which makes the escape sequence `^[[H` or by changing the $TERM you're using (or by editing `~/.inputrc`).

By the way there's no relationship between the tilde you get when you press <kbd>Home</kbd> and the tilde that represents the home directory. For example, in my setup <kbd>Page-Down</kbd> produces `^[[6~` which would also print a tilde if it weren't being properly interpreted.

Comment: Thanks! rxvt fixed the Home key; the End key now produces a ding. PgUp/Down do indeed type `~`, and none of the PuTTY Keyboard settings make them work. Is my bash messed up, or is this "normal"?

Comment: What do you get when you type `echo $TERM`?

Comment: `xterm` (15 character limit argh)

Comment: You can try adding `"\eOw": end-of-line` (that's a capital letter O) to your `~/.inputrc` file.

Comment: End key fixed; I get the idea. Really wish hacks like this weren't necessary though...

Comment: Further documentation is in the man pages for terminfo(5) and readline.

Answer (score 3):

Non of these options worked for me.  I am running an old AIX system.  I had to add the following alias's to my .profile

```
alias __A=$(print '\0020') # ^P = up = previous command
alias __B=$(print '\0016') # ^N = down = next command
alias __C=$(print '\0006') # ^F = right = forward a character
alias __D=$(print '\0002') # ^B = left = back a character
```

Comment: doesn't work for me, bummer

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't get it working with other methods. I however created this AutoHotkey script that works, as long as your shell is Bash:

```
#IfWinActive ahk_class PuTTY
PgUp::Send +{PgUp}
PgDn::Send +{PgDn}
Home::Send ^a   ; beginning of line
End::Send ^e    ; end of line
+^Del::Send ^k  ; delete whole line after cursor
+End::Send ^k   ; delete whole line after cursor
+Home::Send ^u  ; delete whole line before cursor
^Del::Send !d   ; delete word after cursor
^BS::Send ^w    ; delete word before cursor
^Left::Send !b  ; jump word left
^Right::Send !f ; jump word right
#IfWinActive
```

*Use with caution* though, since not all of these bash hotkeys work in other programs.

Comment: This would mess with the main reason I'm looking at this: `screen`, which with the default settings breaks Ctrl-A because it uses it as an escape character....

Comment: @GertvandenBerg FWIW, if you bind it to send ^a followed by another a, `screen` will send a literal CTRL+A, which in bash takes you to the beginning of the line as described. Of course this AHK binding won't work *outside* of `screen`...

Comment: @DoktorJ True, but it would break doing anything else in `screen` that requires the escape sequence (its defaults suck) (The methods tuning the terminal type end up more practical mostly) (I might have been on Solaris servers often when I commented)

Answer (score 1):

### For MTPuTTY

1. Open any connection properties
2. Click `Run PuTTY Config`
3. Open `Connection` > `Data` tab and set `Terminal-type string` to `linux`
4. **Come back to `Session` tab**
5. **Select `Default Settings` in the list and click `Save`**
6. Close the window