# Putty SSH: CTRL+Cursor keys don't work skip to previous/next word

Tags: ubuntu, bash, shell, putty, inputrc

When I am connected to my local Ubuntu dev server with putty (from my Windows 7 box) via SSH, the following key combinations don't work to move the cursor forward and backward on word boundaries:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Left Arrow</kbd> on the cursor pad
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Right Arrow</kbd> on the cursor pad

The cursor only moves one character at a time. I'm using bash.

Comment: bash uses Emacs key bindings by default, so `Alt+B` and `Alt+F` will move backward/forward one word. You can change to vi bindings if you want and move by `w`

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Add these two lines to your `~/.inputrc` file on the destination machine:

```
"\eOD": backward-word
"\eOC": forward-word
```

To make sure that they are the correct sequences, at a Bash prompt, type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>LeftArrow</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>RightArrow</kbd>, you should see:

```
^[OD^[OC
```

When you start a new session, the keys will be available or you can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>x</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>r</kbd> to re-read the `~/.inputrc` file for the current session.

Comment: Would a similar trick work for deleting whole words?

Comment: @Casebash: Try `bind -P | grep kill-word` to show you the existing key bindings for deleting whole words. You can change the bindings in a similar manner to my answer above, if needed.

Comment: I noticed that OpenSuSE (12.3) had bound these sequences already to `backward-char` and `forward-char`, so rather than just adding these lines, I had to replace the lines that already contained the bindings.

Comment: Great! Worked for Ubuntu 14.04 for me, and my putty is running on a Windows 7 box.

Comment: Doesn't work with Putty on win10

Comment: @nZeus: The character sequences may be different in your case. What do the `Ctrl` sequences output for you?

Comment: It works now. I thought I should create this file on the client PC, but I just tried to do it on the server and now it works :+1:

Answer (score 5):

For the Linux console:

```
"\e[1~": beginning-of-line
"\e[4~": end-of-line
"\e[5~": beginning-of-history
"\e[6~": end-of-history
"\e[3~": delete-char
"\e[2~": quoted-insert
```

[7.7. Creating the /etc/inputrc File](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/6.5/chapter07/inputrc.html)