# How do I make ctrl-arrow keys move forward/backward a word at a time in Cygwin bash?

Tags: bash, cygwin

In the default Cygwin installation, using CTRL-LEFTARROW or CTRL-RIGHTARROW simply prints 5C or 5D instead of skipping a word at a time as expected.

Home/End keys work properly, so remapping should be possible.

Comment: Note that this question addresses Cygwin, but can have general application to Unix/Linux systems. If you are using PuTTY and find that the solutions here don't work for you, take a look at [a question specifically about what codes to use for PuTTY](https://superuser.com/q/103069/45163).

Comment: This also happened to me under a full linux; on some advice online, I added a `~/.inputrc` file - which annulled all the linux mint defaults. You can get them back by adding `$include /etc/inputrc` to the top of your ~/.inputrc (assuming that /etc/inputrc is your system-wide inputrc, which it is on Linux Mint)

Answer (score 167):

Found a [solution](http://trumaze.blogspot.com/2011/04/how-to-configure-cygwin-to-use-ctrl.html), posting it here for posterity.

Add the following lines to `~/.inputrc` (`C:\cygwin\home\<username>\.inputrc`):

```
"\e[1;5C": forward-word   # ctrl + right
"\e[1;5D": backward-word  # ctrl + left
```

When done you can press `C-x C-r` to re-read the `.inputrc` file for the current session.

Things to note if you want other similar customisations: Use `5A` and `5B` for up and down arrows, and `2x` for shifted versions.

The "official" key mappings are described in the [Bash Reference Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Line-Editing), but for a quick way to find a key mapping, in bash:

1. type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>
2. type the key sequence you are interested in (e.g., <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd>).  This would print `^[[1;3C`
3. remove the leading `^[` and replace it with `\e` to make `\e[1;3C`
4. place this value in your `.inputrc` file.

Comment: Some keyboard codes are not showing at all like <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>. How do I find these keyboard codes via Mintty/Windows/Cygwin?

Answer (score 21):

You can reload file .inputrc via:

```
bind -f ~/.inputrc
```

[Source](http://blog.bigyanbhar.com/2012/05/reload-inputrc-at-runtime.html)

Comment: This is useful, but not really an answer to the question - perhaps it would be better as a comment to another answer?

Comment: Added to @Tom's answer above

Answer (score 9):

In case you want something that'll work without custom environment settings, for instance when working on a shared account on a server or just to limit the amount of custom configuration being used, Bash has built-ins for this that work in Cygwin.

Namely <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> to move forward and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd> to move backward.

http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Commands-For-Moving.html

Comment: Thanks, though I am aware of those keys and do use them. I just also use the arrow keys when it's convenient and don't want them spewing escape codes instead of doing the sane thing and moving the cursor.

Answer (score 1):

When using rxvt with cygwin I found the solution at this link worked for me: [control_arrow_keys_in_rxvt](http://snarfed.org/control_arrow_keys_in_rxvt_tcsh_and_emacs).

Add the following lines to `~/.inputrc` :

```
"\eOd": backward-word
"\eOc": forward-word
```

Comment: That's when an additional layer is changing the transmitted keys (but it doesn't answer the question asked).

Answer (score 0):

This solution also works in `msys2` consoles:

```
"\e[1;5C": forward-word   # ctrl + right
"\e[1;5D": backward-word  # ctrl + left
```

Just place these key combinations in the `.inputrc` file.

Comment: This is just a part of the accepted answer.