# How to use the shift + arrow keys to select the current terminal command?

Tags: linux, terminal, cygwin, inputrc, xfce4-terminal

I found this https://superuser.com/a/488158/458103 to make the `ctrl+arrow` to move the cursor forward and backward. Now how to make the `shift+arrow` select the current command words?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Execute `cat` and then press the desired keys. You'll see the escape sequences that get printed. E.g. the Right arrow without modifiers will probably produce `^[[C`, with Ctrl modifier it probably gives you `^[[1;5C`, whereas with Shift instead hopefully you'll get `^[[1;2C`.

If you do, modify the config snippet that you linked accordingly (i.e. `2` instead of `5`).

Note that the sequences might vary across terminal emulators, however, you're free to add them all to `~/.inputrc` with the same action.

If you don't get anything printed in the terminal, chances are that you hit a shortcut key of the terminal emulator itself. E.g. for me Shift + Up or Down arrows don't produce anything (rather scroll by a line) in xfce4-terminal.