# How can I get Linux to interpret keyboard characters properly?

Tags: linux, keyboard, shell, putty

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to configure PuTTY so that Home/End/PgUp/PgDn work properly in bash?](https://superuser.com/questions/94436/how-to-configure-putty-so-that-home-end-pgup-pgdn-work-properly-in-bash)

I access a linux server shell via putty, but many of the keys I use do not translate across,
up, down, left and right all are seen as ^[[A, ^[[B, ^[[D and ^[[C;
But so is C-up, C-down, C-left and C-right.
And enter is seen as C-j (which move down to the next line),
and backspace is seen as C-h, which is backwards delete.

How can I stop these keys being translated into other keys (so I can, for example, configure C-h and backspace to perform two different functions) and what's doing this translation (Putty, the kernel, the shell)?

$TERM is 'vt100', which I do have a terminfo file for. I'm actually using PuttyTel, which is like PuttyCyg (it connects to a cygwin process) but I had the same problems running just vanilla Putty.

Can nothing can be done from the server end (if the putty TERM setting isn't sending the desired codes in the first place) and which is the most conservative Putty (or even PuttyCyg/PuttyTel) TERM profile?

Comment: sounds like a duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/94436/how-to-configure-putty-so-that-home-end-pgup-pgdn-work-properly-in-bash ... does that answer your question?

Comment: It seems PuttyTel contains no setting in 'Connection > Data' for changing terminal type :-/

Comment: which version of PuttyTel are you using?  the latest version is 0.60 and has the 'Connection > Data' in the configuration dialog.

Comment: re: server end.  i discussed server-side configuration in my answer to the duplicate: http://superuser.com/questions/94436/how-to-configure-putty-so-that-home-end-pgup-pgdn-work-properly-in-bash/104016#104016 ... re: most conservative.  i'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: if the duplicate link answers your basic questions, you're welcome to edit this post to add your additional questions.  use the gray "edit" link on the question post (below the tags).

Comment: Dammit, it seems I'm using some kind of oddball variant - It seems I might be using PuttyCyg, though it lists both PuttyTel and PuttyCyg in its 'about' page. Anyway, I might be able to change the registry entry for the terminal, I don't know.

Comment: If it's the server configured incorrectly, then what does setting terminal type in putty do? By conservative, I mean preserves keys like enter, instead of interpreting them as C-j.

Comment: puttycyg should be based on putty 0.60 as of the 20071011 release; which are you using?

Comment: setting the term type in putty auto-sets the $TERM variable in your shell.  the server needs a proper terminfo entry for whatever that setting is for things to "just work".

Comment: PuttyCyg 20090811

Comment: Hmmm, I think putty is set to term 'xterm' though...