# Can't get keyboard to work correctly in putty

Tags: ssh, keyboard, putty

I'm using putty on win7 as client, to log into ssh on a debian server. But I've met a strange problem about keyboard behaviors on putty console.

I noticed that it's about keyboard config in putty. After reading [the manual of putty](http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.58/htmldoc/Chapter4.html#config-keyboard), I successfully made `backspace` key to work, but still have troubles about `ESC`, arrows, `home` and `end`, and `F1`-`F12` keys.

[image: Here is my keyboard config in putty]

Here I list their behaviors below. It seems that the mismapping of `ESC` is the root cause.

- `ESC` => ^[
- `up` => ^[OA
- `down` => ^[OB
- `right` => ^[OC
- `left` => ^[OD
- `home` => ^[[1~
- `end` => ^[[4~
- `F1` => ^[[11~
- `F12` => ^[[24~

================================================

Here I will show why I think esc is mismapping:

When in a correctly working ssh console, I press `esc`, it should show nothing.

```
(before)
root@somemachine:
(after)
root@somemachine:
```

But in this malfunctioning ssh console, I press `esc`, it shows `^[`.

```
(before)
root@somemachine:
(after)
root@somemachine: ^[
```

I ran od -c on both ssh console, and pressed `esc`, they gave the same output.

```
(normal one)
root@opengg:~# od -c
^[

(malfunctioning one)
$ od -c
^[
```

Comment: I had the same problem, i solved with this solution: http://superuser.com/a/104001

Comment: this did it for me: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/PuTTY_numeric_keypad_mappings

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The problem is the value of the TERM environment variable does not match the configured terminal characteristics - specifically the "Home and End keys" and "Function keys and keypad" settings.

These can be hard to get right.

### What is expected by the Debian server.

Type `infocmp -I` to see what your computer is expecting.

```
$ infocmp -I 
#       Reconstructed via infocmp from file: /usr/share/terminfo/a/ansi
ansi|ansi/pc-term compatible with color,
        …
        rmul=\E[m, il1=\E[L, kbs=^H, kcbt=\E[Z, kcud1=\E[B,
        khome=\E[H, kich1=\E[L, kcub1=\E[D, kcuf1=\E[C, kcuu1=\E[A,
        …
```

`khome=\E[H` means that the server expects to receive three characters `ESC [ H` when you press <kbd>Home</kbd>.

You can look at what is expected for other values of TERM

```
$ infocmp -I xterm
#       Reconstructed via infocmp from file: /usr/share/terminfo/x/xterm
xterm|X11 terminal emulator,
        …
        is2=\E[!p\E[?3;4l\E[4l\E>, il1=\E[L, ka1=\EOw, ka3=\EOu,
        kb2=\EOy, kbs=\177, kbeg=\EOE, kc1=\EOq, kc3=\EOs,
        kdch1=\E[3~, kcud1=\EOB, kend=\E[4~, kent=\EOM, kf1=\EOP,
        kf10=\E[21~, kf11=\E[23~, kf12=\E[24~, kf13=\E[25~,
        kf14=\E[26~, kf15=\E[28~, kf16=\E[29~, kf17=\E[31~,
        kf18=\E[32~, kf19=\E[33~, kf2=\EOQ, kf20=\E[34~, kf3=\EOR,
        kf4=\EOS, kf5=\E[15~, kf6=\E[17~, kf7=\E[18~, kf8=\E[19~,
        kf9=\E[20~, khome=\E[1~, kich1=\E[2~, kcub1=\EOD,
        kmous=\E[M, knp=\E[6~, kpp=\E[5~, kcuf1=\EOC, kcuu1=\EOA,
        …
```

Here you can see that, if `TERM` were set to `xterm`, this server would expect to receive `ESC [  1 ~` when <kbd>Home</kbd> is pressed (`khome`)

If the above is too cryptic, try `infocmp -L`

You can also do things like `tput khome | hexdump -C` if you know the terminfo capability names for the keys you are interested in.

```
$ tput khome | hexdump -C
00000000  1b 5b 48                                          |.[H|
```

or, arguably more legibly

```
$ tput khome | hexdump -e '12/1 "%3_u" "\n"'
esc  [  H
```

or to see what another TERM setting might mean

```
$ TERM=xterm tput khome | hexdump -e '12/1 "%3_u" "\n"'
esc  [  1  ~
```

if the output is empty the server thinks that terminal type (TERM) doesn't have that key.

### What is actually sent by Putty.

To see what <kbd>Home</kbd> actually sends, run `vi`, press <kbd>i</kbd> (for insert mode) press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> then press <kbd>Home</kbd> and press <kbd>Esc</kbd> to exit insert mode.

### Solution

Adjust Putty config (or TERM) until what is sent matches what the other end expected.

---

E.g.

Do as specified in https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/wishlist/terminfo.html then in Putty, Configuration, Connection, Data, terminal-type string = PuTTY and save that. Maybe.

Comment: Making sense, but the problem is I can't even get `ESC` to work, let alone `home`. Seems like I have to solve `ESC` first, right?

Comment: If the ESC key produces `^[` as output, it works as designed.

Comment: @Rufus: ktf is right. Your problem is not the Esc key since the other key definitions in no way depend on how the Esc key is defined. ^\[ is short for Ctrl+\[, Just as ^A is short for Ctrl+A. [ is the 27th "letter" and Esc is the 27th control code (see [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/))

Comment: For things as standard as Debian and PuTTy, isn't there an off-the-shelf recipe like "upload this config to Debian and this to PuTTy and have the best possible experience ever"?

Comment: @hypersw https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/wishlist/terminfo.html then in Putty, Configuration, Connection, Data, terminal-type string = PuTTY and save that. Maybe.

Answer (score 2):

There is no mismapping of the *ESC* key - ^[ means Control-LeftSquareBracket which is ASCII 27 which is ESC

If you suspect the keys to give wrong sequences, check them with *od -c* and compare them to the *infocmp* output:

```
 $ od -c
 (hit F1 Ctrl-D Ctrl-D)
```

Output may be (`033` is *ESC*):

```
 0000000 033   [   1   1   ~
```

Compare it to the output of infocmp (here `\E` means *ESC*):

```
 $ infocmp -1 | grep 'kf1='
    kf1=\E[11~,
```

Short introduction to infocmp output:

`kbs` = Backspace

`kcub1`, `kcud1`, `kcuf1`, `kcuu1` = Cursor Keys

`kf`* = Function keys

`kpp` / `knp` = Page up/down

`khome` / `kend` = Home / End keys

`kich1` / `kdch1` = Insert / Delete keys

Using these Informations it should be easy to configure your *putty* for your system correctly.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience it's because bash is not running, simply run **/bin/bash** to enjoy colors, history and more. And those glitches disappear moreover, making the keyboard working as expected.

You may have to run this command every time you connect or change user, but it's not hard to remember.

Answer (score 0):

Until you find a full solution try using vi-style keys instead of the arrows.
H => left
J => down
etc.

Answer (score 0):

Certainly there is a "recipe", but PuTTY's developers chose to not participate in the process.  The recipe is referred to as a *terminal description*.  There's been a suitable one in ncurses since [2001](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.src.html#t20011117) (see link for example to [terminal database](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.src.html#tic-putty)).

The terminal description is specified to most applications as the `TERM` environment variable.

Rather than use that "recipe", PuTTY by default sets `TERM` to **`xterm`**, which as you have noticed, does not match the special keys (function, cursor).  That's mentioned in the ncurses FAQ [Why not just use TERM set to "xterm"?](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses.faq.html#xterm_generic)

PuTTY is also mentioned (because of the issue with `TERM`) in the [xterm FAQ](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.faq.html), although there is no section devoted to it, because it is not actually an "xterm".