# Cygwin (and Putty) special keys not working

Tags: ssh, cygwin, putty

**TL;DR:** Cygwin sends like `3D` instead of `alt+arrow` and such.

I've been using Cygwin for years now to ssh into my server.

I'm always struggling with GNU Screen's uncomfortable window handling and a few weeks ago I decided to look after how to switch easily. I found a `.screenrc` example and it set `alt+arrow` for switching. Somehow it did not work as expected. Occasionally (like 99% of the time) it didn't send *(?)* the proper key combination, but `3D` and `3C`. It's the same for every F keys (F1-F12), they become `~`. And not only in Screen or while using SSH, but in a normal local Cygwin window as well.

I tried it in Win 7 and 8.1 and 3 PC's and also tried to change the input language in Windows from Hungarian to English, but it was the same. I even tried it in Putty, almost the same, but it sends `[D`.

Of course, it works in Linux terminal.

What can I do now? I didn't find anything related to this that works and I'd appreciate any help. :)

Comment: I never used Cygwin, but for Putty you should look take a look at settings under Terminal->Keyboard. I don't have a Windows box handy at the moment, but I believe that you should set Function keys to `xterm`.

Comment: Also see [this question](http://superuser.com/questions/342848/cant-get-keyboard-to-work-correctly-in-putty?rq=1)