# windows cmd terminal or git bash or conEmu press up arrow key doesn't set 0x1b 0x5b 0x41 in subshell (using putty plink)

Tags: terminal, putty, plink

I'm using putty's plink command to login to serial console, when press up arrow key, `0x1b 0x5b 0x41` is expected to set to MCU and I can use the shell history. But it doesn't work, it's work in putty GUI.

I tried windows' cmd terminal, conEmu terminal and git bash terminal, all of them doesn't work.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Are you connecting from Windows to Linux? See also the advice in [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/94436/how-to-configure-putty-so-that-home-end-pgup-pgdn-work-properly-in-bash) and also [this one](https://superuser.com/questions/342848/cant-get-keyboard-to-work-correctly-in-putty).

Comment: I'm connecting to an RTOS. Using putty GUI is ok, but putty's command line tool plink doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

From [plink documentation](https://the.earth.li/%7Esgtatham/putty/0.78/htmldoc/Chapter7.html#plink):

> Plink is probably not what you want if you want to run an interactive session in a console window.

---

You probably need PuTTY, which is a real terminal capable of handling non-ASCII key strokes.

If you want to skip PuTTY's configuration GUI and launch it directly as a serial terminal from command line try something like:

```
C:\Putty\putty.exe -serial COM4 -sercfg 115200,8,n,1,X
```