# Disable Windows F15 key

Tags: windows-7, linux, keyboard

I'm using Putty on Windows to connect with remote Linux server. For some reason, windows `F15` kept got pressed (not by myself) and it get translated into `~` remotely. I'm wondering how does this happen and how to prevent this? I'm thinking of disable F15 key through registry but so far I can't make it work.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Definitely F15? *Possibly* related question [here](http://superuser.com/questions/708511/putty-inserts-random-characters-during-a-session). F15 can be accessed by pressing Shift + F3, assuming you have no keyboard faults it may be some third party software emulating it somehow.

Comment: @Jonno Thanks for the link. That is exactly my problem.

Comment: It could be some application to prevent Windows from going to sleep. Some of those use function keys not present on the keyboard.

Comment: The application I wrote to do that for my PC places a shift-on/shift-off in the keyboard buffer, instead of some strange key.. That solved all my problems because I can't type a key in between the on/off.